# Sub menu in wordpress doesn't show

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, show, submenu

I have the next site:

[id.factor.ua](http://id.factor.ua)

> If you open it in IE11, you **cannot** see sub-menu in header.

Please, help me fix it!

Comment: i have check in IE9 and firefox .its works fine.

Comment: i have check IE8 .its works fine.. please remove the cache then try it

Comment: @Neeraj, sorry, I, maybe, write that problem in 11 version. thx.

Answer (score 1):

Not working in IE11 !

well I inspected your code and found that it may be the old `ul.menu li:hover > ul` IE problem.

you can follow these links for further understanding
[Link 1](http://css-plus.com/2010/06/how-to-make-a-jquery-drop-down-menu-with-a-css-fall-back/)
[Link 2](http://alistapart.com/article/horizdropdowns)

Comment: THX! but, if you inspected my code maybe you help me fix it? I have a very big headpain with it yet

Comment: okies..! I going offline for now, I will try find a solution after 3 hrs..:)

Comment: I try yours link's. but it doesn't help me. I cannot understand- WHY!